# Extract raw image source address from a php page

Tags: php, python, selenium

I want to download an image from my university site that you need to log in first. I'm using selenium to login and navigate to the image, the URL of which is

```
https://www.ebooks.ktu.lt/func/skaito2/skf.php?data=S2F0YWxvZ2FzTWFrZXRhc0lEPTExJlVuaUlEPTEyNzc2MzQ2Njg0ZmU4MGFkMWEyZjkw&amp;format=png&amp;page=1
```

When I get there, the source of the page is as following:

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
      <title>skf.php (583×827)</title>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
      <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;background-size: 20px 20px;background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);cursor: zoom-in;" src="https://www.ebooks.ktu.lt/func/skaito2/skf.php?data=S2F0YWxvZ2FzTWFrZXRhc0lEPTExJlVuaUlEPTEyNzc2MzQ2Njg0ZmU4MGFkMWEyZjkw&amp;format=png&amp;page=1" width="194" height="275"></body>
</html>
```

Notice, that

```
src="https://www.ebooks.ktu.lt/func/skaito2/skf.php?data=S2F0YWxvZ2FzTWFrZXRhc0lEPTExJlVuaUlEPTEyNzc2MzQ2Njg0ZmU4MGFkMWEyZjkw&amp;format=png&amp;page=1"
```

It's the same address!

How do I extract the **raw, actual** address of the image so that the source of the page would be binary PNG data?

By the way, Chromium, when asked to download the page with `Ctrl+S`, correctly identifies it **as an image**.

Comment: If I replace &amp; with & I get a PNG: https://www.ebooks.ktu.lt/func/skaito2/skf.php?data=S2F0YWxvZ2FzTWFrZXRhc0lEPTExJlVuaUlEPTEyNzc2MzQ2Njg0ZmU4MGFkMWEyZjkw&format=png&page=1 (This *is* the raw address of the image)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to download an image from my university site that you need to log in first

Not for images obviously - I could get the expected image without being logged in.

> When I get there, the source of the page is as following:

(snip)

This markup is generated by the browser for presentation. Using `python-requests` you get the raw image:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.ebooks.ktu.lt/func/skaito2/skf.php?data=S2F0YWxvZ2FzTWFrZXRhc0lEPTExJlVuaUlEPTEyNzc2MzQ2Njg0ZmU4MGFkMWEyZjkw&format=png&page=1")
>>> r.headers["content-type"]
'image/png'
>>> r.content[:10]
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00'
```